# Different bare repo name cause different config

Tags: git

My system is centos 7.4 with git 1.8.
I found a problem:create bare repo with name `.git` or `name.git` cause different config.

Test as below:

```
[root@localhost repo]# git init --bare site1.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/websites/site1/repo/site1.git/
[root@localhost repo]# git config --list
```

---

```
[root@localhost repo]# git init --bare .git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/websites/site2/repo/.git/
[root@localhost repo]# git config --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=true
```

Notice different `git config --list` result with different bare repo name.

What's the problem?How to solve it?

Comment: `.git` is a directory in `.`, so that you created `./.git`, which is where Git looks for a Git repository, so after you created it, you had one to look in. Meanwhile `site1.git` is a directory in `.`, so that you created `./site1.git`, which is *not* where Git looks for a Git repository—so for the earlier case, `git config --list` was not able to find the just-created repository and list it; it listed only your per-user settings, presumably none.

Comment: @torek,which means I should use `git init --bare .git` to create bare repo?

Comment: No, it means `git init --bare <name>` to create the directory `<name>`. If you want the name to be `.git`, which is the Git repository for the work-tree you're sitting in, that's fine, but kind of weird since a bare repository has no useful files in its work-tree. If you want to inspect the repository named `<name>` after `git init --bare <name>`, use `chdir <name>` to get INTO it first. You can only get away without doing that when the name is `.git`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on torek's comments,we should:

```
git init --bare site1.git
cd site1.git
git config --list
```